# How to bust the cache for the FROM line of a Dockerfile

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have a Dockerfile like this:

```
FROM python:2.7

RUN echo "Hello World"
```

When I build this the first time with `docker build -f Dockerfile -t test .`, or build it with the `--no-cache` option, I get this output:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  40.66MB
Step 1/2 : FROM python:2.7
 ---> 6c76e39e7cfe
Step 2/2 : RUN echo "Hello World"
 ---> Running in 5b5b88e5ebce
Hello World
Removing intermediate container 5b5b88e5ebce
 ---> a23687d914c2
Successfully built a23687d914c2
```

My echo command executes.

If I run it again without busting the cache, I get this:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  40.66MB
Step 1/2 : FROM python:2.7
 ---> 6c76e39e7cfe
Step 2/2 : RUN echo "Hello World"
 ---> Using cache
 ---> a23687d914c2
Successfully built a23687d914c2
Successfully tagged test-requirements:latest
```

Cache is used for Step 2/2, and `Hello World` is not executed. I could get it to execute again by using `--no-cache`. However, each time, even when I am using `--no-cache` it uses a cached `python:2.7` base image (although, unlike when the `echo` command is cached, it does not say `---> Using cache`).

How do I bust the cache for the `FROM python:2.7` line? I know I can do `FROM python:latest`, but that also seems to just cache whatever the latest version is the first time you build the Dockerfile.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understood the context correctly, you can use `--pull` while using `docker build` to get the latest base image -

`$ docker build -f Dockerfile.test -t test . --pull`

So using both `--no-cache` & `--pull` will create an absolute fresh image using Dockerfile -

`$ docker build -f Dockerfile.test -t test . --pull --no-cache`

Issue - https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4238

Comment: Yes! `--pull` is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you!